# Apply styles depending by a event

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

My application represents some boxes on above another and i want to implement the next functionality.
When i am with the cursor over a box, i want to  rotate the box like here: https://codepen.io/Ra1ny/pen/LdwOGG?editors=1111 , but only horizontaly. I tried to do something with `mousemove` but i  could not bind the data with what i want, so at the final i didn't manage. Who knows how to to this?

demo:https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-tesla-71sg2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: your demo is not working

Comment: @d3bgger, now works?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @d3bgger, the code works?